# Periodic boundary condition in solid

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions

I want to solve a small deformation solid structure problem applying periodic boundary conditions in FEM. The geometry is a square and the equations are:
$$
\text{div} \, \sigma = 0 \\
\sigma = f(\epsilon)\\
\epsilon_{ij} = \frac{1}{2}(u_{i,j} + u_{j,i}) \\
u^+ - u^- = c \\
\sigma^+ \cdot \hat{n} + \sigma^- \cdot \hat{n} = 0
$$

The variables with the $.^+$ or $.^-$ correspond to opposite sides in the square.

A weak form the equilibrium equation can be written as:
$$
\int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v) \,dV = 0 \\
$$
where $\delta v$ is a test function. Discretizing by FE and applying Newton-Raphson iterative scheme I wrote a residual of the form:

$$
r = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
  \int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v_j) \,dV \quad \text{ for } j = 1...N_\text{int} - N_\text{ext}/2\\
  u_j^+ - u_j^- - c \quad \text{ for } j = 1...N_\text{ext}/2\\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Question:** The weak formulation above does not have the surface contribution so the correct form is:
$$
\int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v) \,dV + \int_{\partial V}  \sigma \cdot \hat{n} \,  \,dS = 0 \\
$$
If you take the condition $\sigma^+ \cdot \hat{n} + \sigma^- \cdot \hat{n} = 0$, how does the condition $\sigma^+ \cdot \hat{n} + \sigma^- \cdot \hat{n} = 0$ affects that term in order to by enforce ? (It seems that that term should vanish but that did not work for me)

If this is not the correct way how do I enforce the conditions $\sigma^+ \cdot \hat{n} + \sigma^- \cdot \hat{n} = 0$ ?

**Note**: [Here](https://github.com/GG1991/fe2_tests/tree/master/homog_bcs) I have the *octave* code *run_periodic.m* for you to see. The *ass_periodic.m* function do the job of assembly the residual and jacobian and tries to enforce the boundary conditions.

Comment: That boundary condition should be satisfied implícitly

Comment: Indeed. Your weak form is wrong: it needs to contain boundary terms that will allow you to include the periodic boundary conditions.

Comment: I edited the question again adding the surface force contribution. I tried to enforce that "anti-periodic" boundary condition vanishing that term but that did not work.

Comment: What concretely does "did not work" mean?

Comment: That I do not get periodic boundary conditions by doing that. I solved the problem applying Lagrange multipliers. Then I will edited the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could arrive to the solution at the end applying the *Lagrange Multiplier Method. The surface term at the weak form:
$$
\int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v) \,dV + \int_{\partial V}  \sigma \cdot \hat{n} \,  \,dS = 0 \\
$$
should vanish, i.e.:
$$
\int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v) \,dV = 0 \\
$$
because in these problem we are not applying Neumann or Robin Boundary conditions, we are a applying a Dirichlet type:
$$
u^+ - u^- = c
$$
 that we don't know at first the value of $u^+$ and $u^-$. The other thing we know is that the external force applied should be the same :
$$\sigma^+ \cdot \hat{n} + \sigma^- \cdot \hat{n} = 0$$
This mean that is logical to add a Lagrange multiplier in the force term (in the correct degrees of freedom and with the right sign) as:

$$
\int_{V} \text{div} \, \sigma: \epsilon(\delta v_j) \,dV - \lambda_j = 0 \text{ for } j = 1...P
$$
By this way we have added $P$ more unknown $\lambda_j$ to the system. To solve the problem we add the displacement periodic boundary conditions:
$$u_j^+ - u_j^- = c_j \text{ for } j = 1...P.$$
There are other techniques that can be used such as the *Master Slave Method*, *Penalty Method*, *Augmented Lagrangian*, between others. I didn't go deeper with them yet.

Here I give a picture of how a body is deformed under a certain value of $c$ using the Lagrange Multiplier Method :

[image: Body deformed using periodic boundary conditions]

The code to obtained that solution can be seen [Here](https://github.com/GG1991/fe2_tests/tree/master/homog_bcs) and can be executed as:

```
octave run_periodic_lm.m
```